# Trying to Subvectorize Vector of Random [1-100 000] Length

Tags: c++, vector, split

I'm trying to split a variable (1 - 100 000) length vector into random parts for further operation. But my code crashes, and so far, my debugs have been fruitless. Can anyone offer any insight?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void subVectorize() {
//N ways to pick consecutive integer sequences of length M (M < N) K-Vlaue is Kth smallest number   in sequence
//Task: Find smallest possible subsequence

int M = rand() % (100000 - 1);

vector<int> nVector(M); //Vector to store sequence of variable length

for (int i = 0; i < nVector.size(); i++) //Populate the vector
{
    nVector[i] = i;
}

//Split the vector randomly

vector<int>::const_iterator start = nVector.begin() + (rand() % (100000 - 1));
vector<int>::const_iterator end = nVector.begin() + (rand() % (100000 - 1));
vector<int> subVector(start, end);

}
```

Comment: Your `start` can be after `end` and both can be out of range.

Comment: Just caught it and applied a fix - I think! Still trying to figure out randomness; I guess I need to seed it? Is there any way to do this without the time library?

Comment: If I was able to help you please let me know by accepting my answer, or update your question. Also if you found a solution which may be different including it here can help other people find the right solution for their problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void subVectorize( )
{
    //N ways to pick consecutive integer sequences of length M (M < N) K-Vlaue is Kth smallest number   in sequence
    //Task: Find smallest possible subsequence

    int M;
    int randomEnd;
    int randomStart;

    M           = rand( ) % ( 100000 - 1 ) + 1;
    randomEnd   = rand( ) % ( M );

    if( randomEnd == 0 )
    {
        ++randomEnd;
    }

    randomStart = rand() % ( randomEnd );

    vector<int> nVector(M); //Vector to store sequence of variable length

    for ( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < nVector.size( ) ; i++ ) //Populate the vector
    {
        nVector[i] = i;
    }

    //Split the vector randomly

    vector<int>::const_iterator start   = nVector.begin() + randomStart;
    vector<int>::const_iterator end     = nVector.begin() + randomEnd;

    vector<int> subVector( start , end );

}

int main()
{
    srand( time( NULL ) );

    subVectorize( );

    return 0;
}
```

if you adjust it like this, it should work fine.

I've included the pseudo random seed.

Basically your problems were that `start` and `end` could both be out of range and `end` could be before `start` also what if `M` is 0? You can't create a vector with size 0 also your code accessed it anyhow which wouldn't work for a 0 Vector.

```
rand( ) % ( 100000 - 1 ) + 1
```

The +1 is an offset which means it will be your pseudo random number + 1 therefore it can't be 0.

Comment: I chose to approach this in a different manner than subvectorization, but your post was helpful, so I will accept it. My apologies for the delay!